# Update a global data frame through a class method

Tags: python, pandas, class

I would like to append rows in a data frame which is specified as the first argument of the following class and according to a name, which is the second argument, when I instantiate an instance.

My problem is that I would like to update the state of the data frame which is passed as the second argument and when I call it I don't get the updated status.

```
import pandas as pd

class RecordClass(object):
    def __init__(self, df, name):
        self.name = name
        self.df = df

    def write_method(self, *args):
        keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
        dictionary = dict()
        dictionary['name'] = self.name
        for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
            dictionary[key] = args[idx]
        self.df = self.df.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
        df = self.df[keys]
        return self.df

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

data = [1, 2, 3]
instance1 = RecordClass(df1, 'a')
print instance1.write_method(*data)
print 
print df1
```

The result I get is:

```
   key1  key2  key3 name
0   1.0   2.0   3.0    a

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

which means that `df1` is not updated. How can I update `df1` after calling the `write_method` method, without the assignment `df1 = instance1.write_method(...)`?

Comment: I don't see a lot of benefit to wrapping your data-frame with this class, for what it's worth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can't*. `append` is not an inplace operation, and when you reassign `self.df` with the result of the append, you are simply creating a *new* object, completely different from the original, and you are assigning that object to `self.df`. The original object that `self.df` (and `df1`) pointed to is not changed.

If this is important functionality, I can recommend creating a DataFrame with NaN entries, and filling them using `loc` or `[:]` assignment.